# Why is my specific table cell class not changing its vertical alignment?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I've created a specific table cell class to change the vertical alignment of the text in the cell but for some reason I'm getting an error message in my element inspector in my browser and the CSS is the same as the less specific version.

I've attached a screenshot of what is going on. Any ideas of what the error message means and/or how to fix this. I've tried adding !important but that didn't work.

[image: Warning message that I'm not familiar with...]

Click the image to enlarge it.

Comment: "Access denied.
You have accessed a location on this server that is not available.
You may need to Sign in to your account to access this page."

Comment: Sorry about that. I've changed the link this one should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using vertical-align: middle;

'center' is used for horizontal alignment.

Comment: Thanks. Oddly center displays correctly when you edit it in the browser inspector but apparently it doesn't actually work.